# How to expect a message to be send to any instance of a class (twice total) with certain arguments in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When refunding an order we need to deactivate the serials attached with that order. In the spec the order has two serials, ergo I must expect two calls to the API that takes care of deactivating the serials.

I've tried:

```
expect_any_instance_of(Gateway).to receive(:deactivate_dongle).once.with(serial_number: '67890')
expect_any_instance_of(Gateway).to receive(:deactivate_dongle).once.with(serial_number: '12345')
```

Which gives me:

```
The message 'deactivate_dongle' was received by #<Gateway:70179265658480 @connection=#<Faraday::Connection:0x007fa7c4667b28>> but has already been received by #<Gateway:0x007fa7c6858160>
```

Same for:

```
expect_any_instance_of(Gateway).to receive(:deactivate_dongle).with(serial_number: '12345')
expect_any_instance_of(Gateway).to receive(:deactivate_dongle).with(serial_number: '67890')
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you please post the controller's code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you can change your implementation to make your expectations against a known instance of `Gateway` (in order to avoid `expect_any_instance_of`) you could use rspec's [`ordered`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/setting-constraints/message-order) method to add constraints on receiving messages.

I fear in your case you should try to add a spec where there is only one of those serials involved so you can expect it properly. e.g.

```
expect_any_instance_of(Gateway).to receive(:deactivate_dongle).once.with(serial_number: '67890')
```

And then have a spec with n serials and just expect `deactivate_dongle` being called n times.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a [Null Object](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs/as-null-object):

> Use the as_null_object method to ignore any messages that aren't explicitly
>   set as stubs or message expectations.

```
allow_any_instance_of(JarvisGateway).to receive(:deactivate_dongle).as_null_object
```

Here's another solution I thought of before I found the above solution. Blocks offer more flexibility in checking args than the built-in matchers. See [Use a block to verify arguments](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation#use-a-block-to-verify-arguments).

```
allow_any_instance_of(JarvisGateway).to receive(:deactivate_dongle) do |args|
  expect(['67890', '12345']).to include args[:serial_number]
end

expect_any_instance_of(JarvisGateway).to receive(:deactivate_dongle).twice
```

Not sure if `allow_any_instance_of` supports blocks this way.
If it doesn't then you can do it by one or more of the following:

1. Create an instance of `JarvisGateway` and check the messages sent to
   it instead of `allow_any_instance_of`.
2. Use `has_received` instead of `to receive`. See [Spies](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies).

EDIT:
Actually `expect_any_instance_of(JarvisGateway).to receive(:deactivate_dongle).twice` isn't so good because it does not check to see that each serial number was called once.

Comment: @B Seven sorry for the late reply and thanks. will try your suggestions now.

Comment: None of the methods worked, sorry and thanks anyways.

Comment: Just in case it might help anyone: args not working (not accessible) unless I use instead the following: `allow_any_instance_of(JarvisGateway).to receive(:deactivate_dongle) do |object, args|`